# In BigQuery how do I total fields that match the same date and id?

Tags: sql

I have some data in BigQuery that is 3 columns: date, id, quantity. Example:

```
2021-2-2 | abcd | 123
2021-2-2 | abcd | 456
2021-2-1 | efgh | 321
2021-2-1 | efgh | 654
```

I'd like to combine and total where the dates and ids match like so:

```
2021-2-2 | abcd | 579
2021-2-1 | efgh | 975
```

I think the best way to go about this would be to put all of the new data into a new BigQuery table, then delete the old. How would I go about running the query and writing to a new table for a large data set using a Node Cloud Function?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you just want `group by`:

```
select date, id, sum(quantity)
from t
group by date, id;
```

If this answers your question, you should make some effort to learn SQL -- there are many tutorials, books, and online resources that can help.  `GROUP BY` is very basic SQL and some background in the language will help you use BigQuery.